# HtmlAgilityPack - Remove child nodes but retain inner text for the main node without XPath

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have html like:

`<div class="asd">
         lalala
        </br>
        lalala2
        <div>
        aaaaa
        </div>
        </div>`

I need to get only "lalala \n lalala2" without using XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension method for HtmlNode

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{
    public static string InnerText(this HtmlNode node)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var x in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
                sb.Append(x.InnerText);

            if (x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "br")
                sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

just find the node and call node.InnerText()